# Updating div when using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code that displays two rows of colored inputs of type image. When one of the inputs is clicked, it is highlighted with a shadow and the shadow on the previously clicked input is removed. This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/enbuxyaw/) shows it working as non-ajax code.

But this needs to work using ajax. I have setup a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/qnkvm3kc/) trying to show this but it fails to run so I probably don't have the ajax code correctly setup in it. But the ajax works here locally. In my local setup, the clicked on input is shadowed, as it should be, but the previously clicked input stays shadowed.

I found a post that said the div needed to be updated so I added the following but that just made the div disappear.

```
    $("#group_one").load(location.href + "#group_one");
```

Here's the full code. Can someone help with this, please?

```
    <style>
      .imgStr {display:inline-block }
    .selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
    div.shadow { border: 0px solid #3DA1D2; padding: 10px; }
    div.shadow:hover {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div><img src="outside.img"></div>

    <form method="post" action="/echo/html/" ajax="true">
    <div class='container' id="group_one">
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
        <input id="red_1" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
        <input id="yellow_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
        <input id="white_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='container' id="group_two">
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
        <input id="red_2" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
        <input id="yellow_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
      </div>
      <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
        <input id="white_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
      </div>
      <div id="showid"></div>


    <script>
    var last_selected;

    $("input").click(function(){
      var current_selected = $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected");
      $("#showid").text('previous selected = '+current_selected.attr('id'));

      $(this).closest('.container').find(".selected").removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
    </script
```

Comment: `$("#group_one").load(location.href + "#group_one");` will return _the entire page_ - adding the # at the end just tells a browser to scroll to that anchor when it's finished loading. But since you're using ajax that won't apply, and probably it's trying to load an entire HTML page into your div, which won't be valid. You need a server-side URL which will return you only the contents of the div you request.

Comment: 1. the markup is invalid (missing closing tags) 2. there is no "ajax" in the script (besides `ajax="true"` which does absolutely nothing) 3. the closing script-tag is broken 4. there is no `.load(...)` in the script

Comment: I'm confused about the flow of the code. In the first jsfiddle, the shadow changes with each click by using the onclick function. In the second one it does the same but doesn't reset. If I leave that as it is and reload the div with all of the inputs I will lose the selected item. Do I need to store that somehow in the onclick function and then call the reload function with that value? The div is inside of a function and its contents will vary with the calling options, something like this:

Comment: in the second fiddle, you aren't using ajax, you're submitting a whole form. the page is just disappearing because you're trying to load a URL that doesn't exist (via the "action" of the form). When you say " this needs to work using ajax", you need to explain the new requirement  - what is it exactly that you want to load via ajax? The only requirement you've given so far is to change the shadows, which as you've proved in the first fiddle, doesn't need ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you were saying about the jsfiddle but I didn't know how to do it. I finally found an example that got it working, I think. Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/enbuxyaw/1/). For some reason it only works in FF and Chrome. And it has lost the ability to show the selected item. The original jsfiddle and my code here works fine in that respect so it is something with this new jsfiddle that is causing the problem but I don't know how to fix that.

For this new jsfiddle, I need to be able to click on one of the inputs and have it selected (shows by a shadow around it). Then when a different input in that row is clicked, the shadow moves to it. I hope this helps to see the problem.

```
    <style>
    .imgStr {display:inline-block }
    .selected{ box-shadow:0px 12px 22px 1px #333;}
    div.shadow { border: 0px solid #3DA1D2; padding: 10px; }
    div.shadow:hover {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(61,161,210,0.5);
    }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="showform"></div>
    <script> 

    function ShowForm () {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'ajax2.php',
         success: function(data) {

           $("#showform").html(`
             <div class="container" id="group_one">
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
                 <input id="red_1" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
               </div>
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
                 <input id="yellow_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
               </div>
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
                 <input id="white_1" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
               </div>
             </div>

             <div class="container" id="group_two">
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:red">
                 <input id="red_2" class="imgInput selected" name="img_front_group" value="red" type="image" src="red.gif">
               </div>
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:yellow">
                 <input id="yellow_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="yellow" type="image" src="yellow.gif">
               </div>
               <div class="imgStr shadow" style="background:white">
                 <input id="white_2" class="imgInput" name="img_front_group" value="white" type="image" src="white.gif">
               </div>
             <div id="showid"></div>         
            `);
          }
      });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
      ShowForm();

      $("input").click(function(){
        var current_selected = $(this).closest(".container").find(".selected");
        $("#showid").text("previous selected = "+current_selected.attr("id"));
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".selected").removeClass("selected");
        $(this).addClass("selected");  
      });    
    });
    </script>
```